# display attribute to specific customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, dropdown-attribute

I have look for this in google, bing and magento.stackexchange and see nothing about it.

We have a situation: we have make a new attribute in admin and we want this attribute to be visible on front end but only for one type of customer groups and not all.

Can anyone have a solution or maybe module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Google-search ("magento product attribute via customer group") reveals that this question has been asked before on stackoverflow.

"[Displaying custom product attributes based on customer group (Magento)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232901/displaying-custom-product-attributes-based-on-customer-group-magento)"

Summarized:
In the view (probably `app/design/frontend/default//template/catalog/product/view.phtml`) you want to have this logic, use the following code:

```
$_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();

if ($_isLoggedIn == true){
    $_groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          

    if ($_groupId === 'X') {
        // output your product attribute
    }
}
```

`X` being the customer group the attribute should be shown for. Because having scattered random ID's like these in view files is (in my personal opinion) a bad practice, you probably want to abstract that away a bit so you can easily modify the product attributes related to a specific customer group.